# TextMate is only showing some bundles, and not highlighting my code anymore

Tags: textmate

I use TextMate for all my Python programming, but recently it stopped highlighting my Python code. I have also tried YAML, which isn't highlighted either.

When I click Bundles, I only see the "Blogging", "HTML", "Hyperlink Helper" and "JavaScript" bundles.

I would like to just do a clean reinstall of TextMate, but I'm not sure what I should delete. Overwriting the app with a newly downloaded copy doesn't help. I've also tried deleting the application support directory, but that only contained the 3rd party bundles, so that doesn't change anything.

Comment: thx, that was the answer, if you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: unchecking the filters. I thought that it would only filter the list of visible bundles, and after checking the filters, I forgot I checked them. 
I can post it as an answer, but then you don' get the rep for it.

Answer (score 1):

See it this works. Goto Bundle Editor > Reload Bundles.

Comment: nope, it does not. But I suppose textmate automatically does this at startup, and I've restarted textmate multiple times.